# Subscribe Form (Submit Event Tracking in Google Analytics)

Tags: events, google-analytics, submit, tracking

I can't  get Subscribe Form event tracking to submit button press on a site.

The relevant code is :-

**Button Code**

```
type="submit" and value="Subscribe"

<script>
document.addEventListener( 'submit', function( event ) {ga('Subscribe', 'event', 'Subscription Form', 'submit');}, false );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code's wrong, the `Subscribe` method should be replaced with `send` to send events:

What you have:

```
ga('Subscribe', 'event', 'Subscription Form', 'submit');
```

What it should be:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Subscription Form', 'submit');
```

And while you're at it, you might want to leverage the `label` field to provide more info such as the form id:

```
var form_id = ...; // some custom code to fetch form id from submit event
ga('send', 'event', 'Subscription Form', 'submit', form_id);
```

See doc for more info: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: I have tried ga('send', 'event', 'Subscription Form', 'submit'); this but did not work for me. you can check on this link https://www.vertoz.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to:

```
gtag('event', 'submit', {
  'event_category' : 'Subscription Form',
});
```